# How to create virtual NIC and associate them with different vlan

Tags: 12.04, networking

I am trying to connect one physical NIC to two different vlans by creating virtual NIC. Since Switch tags a port with only single vlan ID. 
If I convert the switch port to trunk mode, is there some way to tag virtual nic packets  with certain vlan ID?

I just recently started using Ubuntu, I will much appreciate if answered in detail :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Install the vlan package: `apt-get install vlan` or via software center.
- Load the `8021q` kernel module `sudo modprobe 8021q`.
- Configure a vlan `vconfig add eth0 2`

Now you can configure the interface like a normal one. For example

`ifconfig -a eth0.2`

```
eth0.2    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 54:04:a6:ec:c5:a4  
      inet6 addr: fe80::5604:a6ff:feec:c5a4/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:21 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:4174 (4.1 KB)
```

Comment: Also a good source of information https://wiki.ubuntu.com/vlan

Comment: thanks alot , how can i check the Vlan IDs . Is there a command in to see what are the vlan IDs